# "There was no way could I fall asleep again" - is it right?

Tags: grammaticality

"There was no way could I fall asleep again".
It just sounds logical to me. Is it understandable? Do native speakers say that?

Comment: You should add why you wrote it this way. There may be an underlying issue or grammar point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is ungrammatical and definitely unnatural. The only thing you need to do to make the sentence correct is transpose the subject "I" and the verb "could":

> There was no way **I could** fall asleep again.